# Do an equation for every group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to do a curve fit for every serial number. I want to get a result for c,a,b for every serial number in a different row. My df has around 250,000 rows with around 100 different serial numbers. I don't know every number.

Here is a part of my df:

```
    Date    Hour    Minute  Second  Seriel number   mrwSmpVWi   mrwSmpP
0   04.06.2019  0   0   1   701086  4.2 51
1   04.06.2019  0   0   1   701092  4.6 75
2   04.06.2019  0   0   1   701088  4.3 58
3   04.06.2019  0   0   2   701085  4.2 52
4   04.06.2019  0   0   2   701091  4.5 71
5   04.06.2019  0   0   2   701089  4.3 59
6   04.06.2019  0   0   3   701087  4.0 56
7   04.06.2019  0   0   4   701090  3.8 44
8   04.06.2019  0   10  0   701092  4.3 58
9   04.06.2019  0   10  0   701086  4.3 59
10  04.06.2019  0   10  1   701088  4.4 63
11  04.06.2019  0   10  1   701085  4.4 65
12  04.06.2019  0   10  1   701091  4.5 71
13  04.06.2019  0   10  2   701089  4.5 69
14  04.06.2019  0   10  3   701087  4.4 71
15  04.06.2019  0   10  4   701090  3.5 34
16  04.06.2019  0   20  0   701092  4.3 64
17  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701086  4.4 69
18  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701088  4.3 63
19  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701091  4.5 73
20  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701085  4.2 61
21  04.06.2019  0   20  2   701089  4.4 71
```

This is what I have so far:

```
ohlalala = pd.read_csv('1851_2019.csv', sep=';')
ohlala = pd.DataFrame(ohlalala,columns = ['Serial number','mrwSmpVWi','mrwSmpP']).astype(float)


grouped_data = ohlala.groupby('Serial number')


for group_name, grouped_df in grouped_data:

    x=grouped_df.T.iloc[1]
    y=grouped_df.T.iloc[2]

    def logifunc(x,c,a,b):
        return c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x)))

    result, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x, y, p0=[110,400,-2])
```

This is my outout:

```
1711.73
231.156
0.567459
```

My goal is to get a df like the picture. How can I get every result for the grouped df in a differnet row? [image]

Comment: iterate over the serial numbers using numpy or simple list.

Comment: Don't I have to know the name of the serial numbers for this?

Comment: use df['serial numbers'] and assign it a list

Comment: Thank you for your help. It kind of works :D The problem is in your way it takes more than 5 minutes to run.

Comment: and a differnet question how can I get every result in a different row if I need to use this `result, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x, y, p0=[110,400,-2])` line for the curve fit?

Comment: pls clarify. well for fast i cannot suggest anything becoz python is like super high level so it takes time for big datas to load

Comment: okh, you can create a list and append to it every result that is created and then use that list on your dataframe